# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'naive_bayes'

Tags: python, networking, detection

I downloaded Python code for Network Intrusion Detection from here 
https://github.com/saimkhan92/network_intrusion_detection

While trying to run downloaded code on Python version 3.6.1 and PyCharm IDE
i am getting error:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'naive_bayes'"

at line number 3 and line number 4 with following code respectively:

```
from naive_bayes import Data
from naive_bayes import convert_to_float
```

What I did try:
I tried to install and use module `sklearn.naive_bayes`  but it doesn't have any module with name `Data` and `convert_to_float`, 
I tried to use module `naiveBayesClassifier` but it too doesn't have modules `Data` and `convert_to_float`

I am at beginner level in python and any help with be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @mij for formating question

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to import the sklearn naive_bayes module you should write:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import ...
```

but as you said it doesn't have any module with name Data and convert_to_float. So I think you should ask the author saimkhan92 what is the package he wants to import, as it doesn't seem to be any 'official' one.

Comment: Thank you very much @fabiob, me too have same thoughts but saimkhan92 isn't replying, :(